# Django form - DELETE and PUT http method

Tags: django, rest

I would like to use a middleware or something like that in a Django form in order to have the support of the PUT and the DELETE HTTP method.

**My first question is :**
What's the best and easy way to do that ?

Google suggests me to use something like that : https://gist.github.com/1161423

Is it really the best way ? Nothing else ?

**My second question is** : Is it safe ? (csrf for example)

Comment: Rather than implement REST from grounds up, why not use an existing framework (TastyPie, Piston, Django-rest etc.)? Many of the issues you will face will have been solved for you, like security, authentication, authorization, ORM manipulation, serialization etc.